# Hibernate/JPA OneToOne shared key without generated value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

Using: SpringBoot, Kotlin and Hibernate/JPA, MariaDB (doesnt think it matters)

I'm facing something curious about Hibernate/JPA (but I hope Hibernate can handled my problem), the following code doesnt work, i got this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'book_id' cannot be null
Query is: insert into book_detail (pages, book_id) values (?, ?), parameters [48,<null>]
```

Book.kt

```
@Entity
data class Book(

  @Id
  val id: Int = 0,

  val name: String? = null

) : Serializable {

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "book", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
  var details: BookDetail? = null

}
```

BookDetails.kt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_detail")
data class BookDetail(

  @Column(name = "pages")
  var pages: Int? = null,

  @Id
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
  var book: Book? = null

) : Serializable
```

But then if I add on the primary key of Book.kt a generatedValue, then it will work and persist the entities.

Book.kt

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 val id: Int = 0
```

But I doesnt want to let Hibernate generate the ID, when I inspect in my IDE i can see that all entities are correctly set (the link between Book <-> BookDetails seem goods)

So why is it working with an auto generated ID and not when I set the ID myself ?

Code used for persisting entities :

```
 val id = 2
 val book = repo.findById(id).orElse(Book(id = id))
 book.name = "Book B"

 val details = BookDetail(48)
 details.book = book

 book.details = details

 repo.save(book)
```

Comment: Why is `id` nullable in the first place? Try changing it to a standard non-nullable Kotlin type.

`  @Id
  val id: Int,`

Comment: Yeah it was not null on my first try, but it doesnt make a difference, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, the ID shouldn't be nullable, since that would contradict the idea of an ID.

I think what you're looking for is an embedded ID:

```kotlin
@Embeddable
data class BookId(val value: Long) : Serializable

@Entity
data class Book(
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = Column(name = "book_id"))
  val id: BookId(0),
  val name: String? = null
)
```

You set the ID by creating a `BookId` object and passing it to the constructor:

```
val myBook = Book(BookId(42), "Moby Dick")
```

Don't forget to implement an `AttributeConverter` for the ID class:

```kotlin
@Converter
class BookIdConverter : AttributeConverter<BookId, Long> {
  override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(bookId: BookId): Long = bookId.value
  override fun convertToEntityAttribute(dbId: Long) = BookId(dbId)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire code for the converter and the usage ? I now struggle to set the ID using a Long since the type is now a BookId in the constructor

Comment: After a few try, the converter doesn't seem to be invoked. I have added this line on the ID of the EmbeddedId : `@Convert(attributeName = "value", converter = BookIdConverter::class)` But got a new error : **MappingException: No type name**